# Node.js Hello world script not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I just grabbed that code from an online tutorial:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, 'my.ip.is.here');
console.log('Server running at http://my.ip.is.here:3000/');
```

When i start:

```
node app.js
```

I get the following error:

> events.js:48
>           throw arguments[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now); // Unhandled 'error' event
>                          ^ Error: accept ENOSYS
>       at errnoException (net.js:614:11)
>       at TCP.onconnection (net.js:788:24)

I am on a ubuntu 11.10 server VPS, i have nginx as web server but it s not started.

Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: ENOSYS occurs when the system doesn't support a function. It might be something to do with being on a VPS - have you tried this on a local machine?

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working. In a few days you'll be able to accept your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of node.js was from the git rep i tried to nodejs.org one and it now works fine.