# How to setup a Node.js application as a service on Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, service, redhat

I created a node.js application. It is a web server with the Express framework. I can start it with the command `node server.js`. This application is deployed on a Red Hat Enterprise server.

I want this applicaion can:

1. Start automatically when the OS is started.
2. Restart automatically when it crashes.

I think OS service can meet my requirements, right? Is there any clue how to setup the Node.js application as service on Red Hat?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `node.js` as service with [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever), and run nginx webserver as front end server, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now)