# nginx reverse proxy setup does not preserve session id when doing CORS requests

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, cors, reverse-proxy

Here's my setup:
- I have an http server implemented in nodejs that exposes api endpoints. This is reverse proxied through nginx to `api.domain.com` with ssl. Here's the config:

```
 1 server {                                                           
 2     listen 80;                                                      
 3     server_name api.domain.com;                                     
 4     access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access.log;                       
 5     location / {                                                    
 6         proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3000/;                       
 7     }                                                               
 8 }                                                                   
 9                                                                     
 10 server {                                                           
 11     listen 443;                                                    
 12     server_name api.domain.com;                                    
 13     access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access.log;                      
 14     ssl on;                                                        
 15     ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl/server.crt;     
 16     ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/server.key;         
 17     location / {
 18         proxy_pass    https://127.0.0.1:3001/;                                
 19     }                                                              
 20 }
```

Then I have nginx delivering a static context file under `dashboard.domain.com` that is intended to consume the api from `api.domain.com`. Here is the setup:

```
  1 server {                                                                                                                                 
  2     listen 80;                                                                  
  3     server_name dashboard.domain.com;                                        
  4     root /path/to/static/site;                                                                                             
  5 }
```

I want to do this using CORS, I made sure the js on the static site is sending the correct `Origin` header in all requests. I implemented a very simple login mechanism. Here's the coffeescript code I'm using on the api endpoint:

```
# server.coffee
app.configure ->
    app.use middleware.setP3PHeader()
    app.use express.bodyParser()
    app.use express.cookieParser()
    app.use express.session
      secret: conf.session.secret
      key: conf.session.key
      cookie:
          maxAge: conf.session.maxAge
    app.use express.methodOverride()
    app.use express.query()
    app.use express.errorHandler()

# routes.coffee
app.options '*', shop.cors, shop.options
app.post '/login', shop.cors, shop.login
app.post '/logout', shop.cors, shop.logout
app.get '/current-user', shop.cors, shop.current

# shop.coffee
exports.options = (req, res) ->
    res.send 200

exports.cors = (req, res, next) ->
    allowed = ['http://dashboard.domain.com', 'http://localhost:3000']
    origin = req.get 'Origin'
    if origin? and origin in allowed
        res.set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin
        res.set 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true
        res.set 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST'
        res.set 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type'
        next()
    else
        res.send 403, "Not allowed for #{origin}"

exports.login = (req, res) ->
    unless req.body.email? and req.body.password?
        res.send 400, "Request params not correct #{req.body}"
    models.Shop.findOne()
        .where('email').equals(req.body.email)
        .where('password').equals(req.body.password)
        .exec (err, shop) ->
            if err? then return res.send 500, err.message
            unless shop? then return res.send 401, "Not found for #{req.body}"

            req.session.shopId = shop.id
            res.send 200, shop.publish()

exports.logout = (req, res) ->
    delete req.session.shopId
    res.send 200

exports.current = (req, res) ->
    unless req.session.shopId?
        return res.send 401, "Not logged in!"
    models.Shop.findById(req.session.shopId)
        .exec (err, shop) ->
            if err? then return send.res 500, err.message
            unless shop? then return res.send 404, "No shop for #{req.session.shopId}"

            res.send 200, shop.publish()
```

The problem is this:
1. I first make a call to `/login` and I get a new session with a logged in user (`req.session.shopId`)
2. Then I call `/current-user` but the session is gone! The session id received by the nodejs server is different and thus it creates a different session

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have a global proxy directive (`proxy_pass`), but you're not explicitly handling header forwarding (where, presumably the session token lives as a cookie), and further you need to think about what constitutes a (shared) session cache key.

Might try something like this:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000/;                                
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
   proxy_set_header   Host  $http_host;
   proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy  true;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_cache pcache;
   proxy_cache_key   "$scheme$host$request_method$request_uri";
}
```

Also, if the node.js server is on the same box, not sure why you would connect via ssl on localhost (`proxy_pass  https://127.0.0.1:3001/`). You might want to consider exposing an SSL-only public face with a rewrite directive by doing a: `rewrite  ^ https://api.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;`

See also: [Node.js + Nginx - What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now) [SO] on basic setup, and http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4408747 for a good discussion on lost (and worse - leaked!) sessions from a nginx reverse proxy configuration snafu.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have session persistence, you need to be sure that you configured `express-session` module correctly. `resave` and `saveUninitialized` parameters are important.

From docs:

> **resave**
>
> Forces the session to be saved back to the session store, even if the
>   session was never modified during the request. Depending on your store
>   this may be necessary, but it can also create race conditions where a
>   client makes two parallel requests to your server and changes made to
>   the session in one request may get overwritten when the other request
>   ends, even if it made no changes (this behavior also depends on what
>   store you're using).
>
> The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated,
>   as the default will change in the future. Please research into this
>   setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case. Typically,
>   you'll want false.
>
> How do I know if this is necessary for my store? The best way to know
>   is to check with your store if it implements the touch method. If it
>   does, then you can safely set resave: false. If it does not implement
>   the touch method and your store sets an expiration date on stored
>   sessions, then you likely need resave: true.
>
> **saveUninitialized**
>
> Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A
>   session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified. Choosing
>   false is useful for implementing login sessions, reducing server
>   storage usage, or complying with laws that require permission before
>   setting a cookie. Choosing false will also help with race conditions
>   where a client makes multiple parallel requests without a session.
>
> The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated,
>   as the default will change in the future. Please research into this
>   setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case.
>
> Note if you are using Session in conjunction with PassportJS, Passport
>   will add an empty Passport object to the session for use after a user
>   is authenticated, which will be treated as a modification to the
>   session, causing it to be saved.

One of my applications has this and it's working:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: config.redis_instance_local_ip,
        port: config.redis_instance_local_port
    }),
    secret: config.application_session_secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Additionally, if you want to have sticky sessions (or session persistence) over multiple nodes load balanced by nginx, you should have commercial version of nginx, nginx plus. See http://nginx.com/products/session-persistence/