# Mean stack / node website port

Tags: node.js, url, mean-stack, www-mechanize

When im using MEAN stack, I always needs to visit the url like

```
example.com:3000
```

*How do I remove the port in the url?*

To:

```
example.com
```

Comment: @iSkore im using Mean stack, that includes express. what is the default port i need to change it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap your port to listen to `port 80`

HTTP is 80

HTTPS is 443

Example:

```
const express = require( 'express' ),
      app = express();

app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    res.send( 'hello world' );
} );

app.listen( 80 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change the domain that you access the website with you can add that domain to your hosts file in addition to changing the port to `80`.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33682007/3753389