# Node Js express serve website with project name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a simple node js application with Node and Express. It just used to serve couple of static files. It is serving files as

```
http://localhost:3000/index
http://localhost:3000/users
```

But I want to serve it with a project name. some thing like as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/myNodeProject/index
http://localhost:3000/myNodeProject/index
```

How do I do that ?

My Code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Routers or HTTP Rest Requests
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Comment: I don't think it works like that. Nodejs sets up its own server and you can access that at root level. You can use different ports for different projects. You can use the url pattern you mentioned by mounting different roots.

Comment: Mohit is right, however in production. You can use something like Apache or Nginx to forward anything that starts with http://localhost:3000/myNodeProject to your Node.Js application. You are able to do this in development too, however it doesn't grant any benefits.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516810/how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-node-js-server  take a look at this question