# Add domain on the node project

Tags: node.js

My node project is runing on the http://localhost:3000. 
I want to put the node code on the Ubuntu live server.

I want my node project running on the my domain.

Please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517970/10967697 hope this answer will help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign a domain name to node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516810/how-to-assign-a-domain-name-to-node-js-server)