# Can Host Headers resolved to a virtual host node.js like in Apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, dns, http-headers

[Host headers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68854/how-do-apache2-virtualhosts-get-resolved) cause a webserver to return a different `virtual host` based on which DNS name the DNS server resolved to send the browser to the servers ip.  Is it possible to build this sort of functionality into a node.js http server between multiple deployed apps?

(Of course you could just use Apache to do this, but can it be done without Apache?)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254583/how-do-i-host-multiple-node-js-sites-on-the-same-ip-server-with-different-domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly implement this same behavior in node. The `http` module only provides a basic server instance with a `request` callback, but you can expand on that by checking the `Host` header and then routing the request to the proper application.

If you are using an server framework like `express` or `connect`, there is a [`vhost`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/vhost.js) middleware that will provide this functionality.