# webserver node.js as non root user

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, webserver

I'm a Linux beginner and have a Linux Ubuntu 12.04 server. I've installed node.js and created a webserver script. That works fine, but it runs as root user.

I know that's not good (root-user & webserver = unsafe).

How can I run the webserver script as an non-root user? Does somebody know a good detailed tutorial or can give me some advice?

Comment: http://vimeo.com/25731567

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

**Listen on port 80**

Run as root, start your app's `listen()` on port 80 and them immediately drop to non-root. This is what Apache does, for example. **Not recommended** since it's easy to get this wrong, and lots of other details (writing to log files, initialization required before you can listen, etc.). Not standard practice in node.

**Listen on port >=1024***

Run as non-root, listen on a port >= 1024 (say: 8000, or 8080), and have someone else listen on port 80 and relay port 80 traffic to you. That someone else can be:

1. A load-balancer, NAT, proxy, etc. (Maybe an EC2 load balancer if you're running on EC2, e.g.)
2. Another http server, say Apache httpd or ngnix.

For an ngnix example, see this: [Node.js + Nginx - What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now)

Answer (score 0):

you can just run `node hello.js`