# Vagrant Node Nginx Dev VM

Tags: node.js, nginx, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to get an reusable Vagrantfile for Node projects using Vaprobash. I'm running to trouble with the Nginx part of the set up. This is the Vaprobash Nginx.sh set up file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Test if PHP is installed
php -v > /dev/null 2>&1
PHP_IS_INSTALLED=$?

echo ">>> Installing Nginx"

[[ -z "$1" ]] && { echo "!!! IP address not set. Check the Vagrant file."; exit 1; }

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    public_folder="/vagrant"
else
    public_folder="$2"
fi

# Add repo for latest stable nginx
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable

# Update Again
sudo apt-get update

# Install the Rest
sudo apt-get install -y nginx

echo ">>> Configuring Nginx"

if [[ $PHP_IS_INSTALLED -eq 0 ]]; then

    read -d '' PHP_NO_SSL <<EOF
        # pass the PHP scripts to php5-fpm
        # Note: \.php$ is susceptible to file upload attacks
        # Consider using: "location ~ ^/(index|app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {"
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param LARA_ENV local; # Environment variable for Laravel
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        }
EOF

    read -d '' PHP_WITH_SSL <<EOF
        # pass the PHP scripts to php5-fpm
        # Note: \.php$ is susceptible to file upload attacks
        # Consider using: "location ~ ^/(index|app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {"
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param LARA_ENV local; # Environment variable for Laravel
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        }
EOF
else
    PHP_NO_SSL = ""
    PHP_WITH_SSL = ""
fi

# Configure Nginx
# Note the .xip.io IP address $1 variable
# is not escaped
cat > /etc/nginx/sites-available/vagrant << EOF
server {
    listen 80;

    root $public_folder;
    index index.html index.htm index.php app.php app_dev.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://set-ip-address.xip.io
    server_name $1.xip.io;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/vagrant.com-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vagrant.com-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /app.php?\$query_string /index.php?\$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    $PHP_NO_SSL

    # Deny .htaccess file access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/xip.io/xip.io.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/xip.io/xip.io.key;

    root $public_folder;
    index index.html index.htm index.php app.php app_dev.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://set-ip-address.xip.io
    server_name $1.xip.io;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/vagrant.com-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vagrant.com-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /app.php?\$query_string /index.php?\$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    $PHP_WITH_SSL

    # Deny .htaccess file access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
EOF

# Turn off sendfile to be more compatible with Windows, which can't use NFS
sed -i 's/sendfile on;/sendfile off;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Nginx enabling and disabling virtual hosts
curl -L https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fideloper/8261546/raw/ngxen > ngxen
curl -L https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fideloper/8261546/raw/ngxdis > ngxdis
sudo chmod guo+x ngxen ngxdis
sudo mv ngxen ngxdis /usr/local/bin

# Setup the vhost generator script for nginx
# This sould be used for the above setup eventually, rather
# than the hard-coded config above!
curl -L https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fideloper/9063376/raw/ngxhost.sh > ngxvhost
sudo chown root:root ngxvhost
sudo chmod guo+x ngxvhost
sudo mv ngxvhost /usr/local/bin

# Disable "default", enable "vagrant"
sudo ngxdis default
sudo ngxen vagrant

if [[ $PHP_IS_INSTALLED -eq 0 ]]; then
    # PHP Config for Nginx
    sed -i "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/" /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

    sudo service php5-fpm restart
fi

sudo service nginx restart
```

Mainly it's a lot of looking for PHP which I'm trying to get removed. I found this topic [Node.js + Nginx - What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now) about setting up Nginx and Node but following that I can never get a return from the server when the server.js script is running. I just get a Nginx Forbidden error, which goes away if I add an index.html page.

What's the best way to modify this file so it will proxy to a node script running on port 3000?

Comment: That looks awefully complicated. Why are you using something for nginx+php if you want node? I'd advice you to start with the following: Install node and expose port 3000 (using forwarded_port from vagant config). If this works, you can install apache and set up a virtual host for your node app.

Comment: This is overly complex, but I wanted to try and keep some of the settings from it like setting an ip for the VM, also this is trying to use Nginx for the proxy not apache. I'm just so new to Nginx config that I'm looking for some guidance in modifying this.