# My site static files are not served (node app on Amazon AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I installed a simple node.js / express website using the instructions on this page:
http://techprd.com/setup-node-js-web-server-on-amazon-ec2/

It seems like that everything is working well when i specify the port number (5000), as you can see in the following:
http://aws.deliverightlogistics.com:5000/

however, when you remove the port number, all the static files cannot be found and you can see the result here:
http://aws.deliverightlogistics.com/

The node/express page saving looks like this:

```js
app.get('/images/*', function(req,res) {
  var url = __dirname + '/public' + req.url;
  res.sendfile(url);
});

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  var home = __dirname + '/public/index.html';
  res.sendfile(home);
});
```

Is there anything i'm missing here?

Thx

Comment: Can you add some middleware to log the requests coming into your server? Did you check the case of the file names?  Did you try requesting the resources one at a time and see what happens on the server?  Is  it getting handled by another route handler up the stack?  I think we need to see a bit more...  Are both sites running the same code?

Comment: let me know what kind of logs I should add and I'll do that...

Comment: In the middleware I would log the path of the object being requested.  I would also consider hard coding the complete paths to some resources and see if it is an issue with the wild carding...

Answer (score 0):

add the following configuration so that Nginx acting as a proxy redirect to port 3000 traffic from the server when we come from “subdomain.your_domain.com"

See the original post:

[Node.js + Nginx - What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-and-now)