# Use Node.js as data source for highcharts

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

I am newbie with nodejs, now i want to use node js as data source (before this i am using ajax to request new data, but it's not good as node js) for my line chart which  make by highcharts. Anyone please help me to point me to right direction, i don't know where to go that can help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You've mixed some things together. Ajax is for sending HTTP requests from client side to server, but NodeJS is server side technology which can generate data for your charts (like PHP, ruby etc.). It depends on your needs, but ajax is the simplest way to retrieve the data from server. Another option is to choose alternative technology like Socket.io.

As for start I suggest you to take a look at these links:

- [basic setup for nodejs+nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now)
- [socket.io getting started](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Comment: i just want to retrieve my data by node js but nothing else. :(

Comment: Yeah, but NodeJS is not for "retrieving data". For getting data from server (NodeJS, PHP, ruby, ...) You need to use HTTP or WebSocket transport protocols.

Comment: oh yes, i don't know that. So i must use Socket.io to connect to Nodejs server. :)