# How do I route some URL patterns to a specific port?

Tags: node.js, routes, port, varnish

I have a node server running on port 3000. I'll be using it to handle all my APIs, but I don't want the URLs to be in the format

```
example.com:3000/api/xyz
```

I want it to be in the format:

```
example.com/api/..
```

How do I route all /api/ calls to port 3000?

example.com will be serving HTML pages, which have nothing to do with node. Node will only be used for APIs for now. I found Varnish, but it looks like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to put nginx in front of your node server.

You can setup nginx to serve static media based on url patterns.  You can also register non-static requests to be sent to an upstream node.js server on port 3000

[Node.js + Nginx - What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now)