# How to config nginx to proxy to rails app? so that i dont have to say domain.com:port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, proxy, unicorn

**Update:**  Currently i visit my app at domain.com:3000, but i would like to visit domain.com to see my app
I have setup nginx at 80 to proxy my rails app at 3000. below is the configuration

```
upstream railsapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name APP;

  # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
  root /var/www/APP/current/public;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # Static assets are served from the mentioned root directory
location / {
    root /var/www/APP/current;
    index index.html index.htm;

    proxy_pass http://railsapp/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    # proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
    # proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}

  # Turn on Passenger
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/wrappers/ruby;
}
```

i referred to :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015178/1124639

this is located at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/APP.conf` and is included in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf as below within `http{...}`

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

but my APP.com still shows 'Welcome to nginx on Ubuntu!' and APP.com:3000 shows my app. What am i doing wrong?

What i am using: 
Ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance
nginx 1.8.0
unicorn server at 3000

Comment: remove the `upstream` server info then restart nginx.

Comment: @Emu i commented upstream and changed proxy_pass, restarted nginx. still not resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to run unicorn so i can fork my app to multiple instances. I guess the issue here was, i set passenger_enabled on and was actually running unicorn on 3000.

so instead i ran passenger

```
passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d -e production
```

and my nginx conf like this,

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.APPNAME.com;

# Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
root /var/www/APPNAME/current/public;
index index.html index.htm;

# Static assets are served from the mentioned root directory
location / {
#  root /var/www/APPNAME/current;
#  index index.html index.htm;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
# proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
# proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}

# Turn on Passenger
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/wrappers/ruby;
}
```

and everything works now!

Answer (score 1):

You just to add a new server{} block and add passenger_root. This is what I did. Then after configuring, try server_name:port "APP.com:3000" on your browser.

```
upstream railsapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

// add new server block here... modify with below example.
server {
    listen *:3000;
    server_name  APP.com;
    rack_env development;
    root /directory/to/rails-app/public;
    index  index.html index.htm index.html.erb;
    passenger_enabled on;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name APP;

  # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
  root /var/www/APP/current/public;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # Static assets are served from the mentioned root directory
location / {
    root /var/www/APP/current;
    index index.html index.htm;

    proxy_pass http://railsapp/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    # proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
    # proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}

  # Turn on Passenger
  passenger_enabled on;
  //add passenger_root
  passenger_root /directory/to/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/wrappers/ruby;
}
```