# Connect to MySQL in javascript server side without node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, nginx

I have a javascript application running with server like `nginx` or `eclipse local server`, and i would like to know if it is possible to connect it with mysql server database.

I know that they are a lot of `npm packages` for `nodejs` application, but i don't want to use node js because if i'll do that i have to implement all structure of nodejs application with all dependencies and i don't know very well this technology to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to connect to a remote database server directly from JavaScript running in a browser… and if there was it would probably involve a huge security hole since anyone with access to the client could take your credentials and run any SQL they like on the server. It is unlikely you could make your database GRANTS fine-grained enough for public consumption.

If you want your client side JS to interact with your database server then you need to write a webservice for it. You can do that in Node.JS or any other server side environment you like.

If you are using Node.JS then you will probably want Nginx to [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now) the requests.

Nginx supports [FastCGI](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/) so you could write in any language that supports FastCGI such as [Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::FCGI) or [PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).