# nginx error: (99: Cannot assign requested address) on Ubuntu for a Node app

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

Please see EDIT2 on the bottom for updated question

I am trying to setup a web application with Node.JS hosted via DigitalOcean on an Ubuntu droplet (not sure if relevant). The [support tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) call for setting up an nginx server to serve the app to the domain. I got to the part where it asks to restart nginx, but it failed on my droplet. I then found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443775/nginx-failing-to-reload-how-to-track-down-why) that answers how to tests the nginx config and return a more verbose error, which was:

```
user@droplet:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "[my domain.ext here]" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [droplet ip here]:8080 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I tried messing around some more and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now) that offers a slightly different way to setup an nginx server, but I still get the same error. I'm really not sure what the problem is anymore and was looking for some guidance on where I can find the solution.

Thank you

EDIT: My nginx.conf file is below. I haven't changed anything in it:

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }


    #mail {
    #   # See sample authentication script at:
    #   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    # 
    #   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
    # 
    #   server {
    #       listen     localhost:110;
    #       protocol   pop3;
    #       proxy      on;
    #   }
    # 
    #   server {
    #       listen     localhost:143;
    #       protocol   imap;
    #       proxy      on;
    #   }
    #}
```

EDIT2: Below is /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default. I got it such that if you go type the public ip address into your browser address bar, it serves the index file correctly. But if you go to the [domain.ext], theres just the "server not found" error the browser throws. I assume its something simple with the configuration now, but I am still lost.

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
# works if you go to the ip address, but not the domain
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name [domain.ext];
    root /home/yazan/;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://[droplet public ip address]:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your config file is not setup correctly (eg, it seems to be trying run your site on "[my domain.ext here]").

You can output the contents of your config file by entering this command: `cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` - then post it here.

Comment: Done, I didn't edit anything in it because the tutorials don't mention changing anything in it

Comment: That is only part of your configuration. The interesting bits are in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` and/or `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`.

Comment: I have nothing in the conf.d directory, but I posted the file from sites-enabled.