# How to using nginx as a proxy server for mean stack?

Tags: node.js, nginx, vagrant, mean-stack, mean

I just installed mean stack app. I'm using nginx as a proxy for mean.
Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name meanjstest.local;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.250.0.100:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

When I ran mean app by `meanjstest.local`. The browser responsed **502 Bad Gateway**. But when I added port `3000` into url, it's ok. How can I remove port number in my url? Do you have any solution for me.
I'm using centos 7 on vagrant box. My vagrant public IP is: `10.250.0.100`. And when I access this IP, it response **Welcome to nginx...**. And the port number `3000` follow, it the same as `meanjstest.local:3000`

Comment: Did you try to access the link: `http://10.250.0.100/` Or try to change `proxy_pass "httlp://localhost:3000"`?

Comment: ah no, I'm using nginx and virtual domain. We can't access through localhost

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5015178/4296747

Comment: i already tried to do this. But the same as my problem