# NodeJS & Nginx Proxy not working

Tags: node.js, nginx

I've written a sailsjs based application, deployed in one of my VPS. App is running in production mode using pm2. I can access through **public_ip:1338**, everything seems normal.

So installed nginx,configured proxy_pass, installed letsencrypt ssl. When I'm trying to access domain, I'm seeing Nginx Default Page with SSL working, not the NodeJS (SailsJS) application.

Here is nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.net www.domain.net;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem;

    server_name domain.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1338;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I need to sort out the issue. Can you guys instruct me to fix the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js + Nginx - What now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now)

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate because I've read that, tried but failed. I didn't ask what's now?, I mentioned **what I wanted** and **what I tried**.

Comment: Did you include `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in nginx.conf file ?

Comment: I've placed the conf file within **/etc/nginx/conf.d** directory.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-configure-tlsssl-on-web-server-(nginx)) and it worked. I did need to include `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` in nginx.conf to make it work. And here's what's in my default file in the `sites-enabled` folder:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH$
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

location ~ /.well-known {
     allow all;
}


location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```