# HTTPs with expressjs staticFile for SPA

Tags: node.js, express, https, routes, single-page-application

I've been digging through tones of websites/tutorials trying to find an answer to my question. Perhaps I am misunderstanding few of the ideas regarding HTTPS.

Right, straight to the point...
I host my SPA frontend app on express(4) using staticFiles pointing to index.html:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const auth = require('http-auth');
const app = express();
const basic = auth.basic({
    file: `${__dirname}/login`
});

app.use(auth.connect(basic));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

However it only runs on HTTP, I'd like to host it using HTTPS (backend also utilizes HTTPS for its requests).

I understand that HTTPS requires some sort of encryption so the request won't be send in plain text, but is it also required from frontend-hosted apps? If so, how would it be achievable?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice is to host node.js applications under proxy (like nginx which is [commonly used for this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now)) because you can't start node.js application on 80 / 443 port without root privileges (and using sudo for it is [security issue](http://syskall.com/dont-run-node-dot-js-as-root/)).

With this in mind - this proxy is the best way for https setup. For example here is step-by-step tutorial for securing [nginx with letsencrypt under ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04). You can find similar tutorials for your OS and other web servers.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I'd like to ask one more question, how would one always redirect from http to https ?

Comment: You should add to your configuration something like https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx