# WebSocket error, Unexpected response code: 200 with Nginx and Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

I'm using a Ubuntu server on DigitalOcean to host an Nginx web server and a Node app that runs a WebSocket server. When attempting to connect to the IP of the server, I get the following message in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://<server's public IP>' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

All I did to set up Nginx was to follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart), which simply tells you to install Nginx and adjust the UFW firewall. I didn't set up server blocks in Step 4, and I haven't touched any other config files.

After that, I put my `index.html` and `client.js` files in the `/var/www/html` directory to be served by Nginx.

`index.html` is a very simple HTML page that runs `client.js`. That JS file looks like this:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://<public IP, same as above>:80');

ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
    const json = { message: 'hello from client!' };
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
    ws.send(jsonString);
});

ws.addEventListener('message', event => {
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

The server side Node app is `websocket.js`, and it looks like this:

```
const buffer = require('buffer');
const http = require('http').createServer();
const ws = require('ws');
const wsServer = new ws.Server({ server: http });

wsServer.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log('received: ' + msg);
        socket.send(Buffer.from('hello from the server!'));
    });

    const json = { message: 'hello from server!' };
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
    socket.send(Buffer.from(jsonString));
});

http.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on 8080'));
```

This file was placed at `/root` along with `node_modules`, `package.json`, and `package-lock.json`. Serving it alongside the client side code at `/var/www/html` didn't help. Of course, it was also running thanks to PM2, and I have also tried running without PM2 which made no difference.

Any help is appreciated, please let me know if there's any information I might have missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there are some extra steps you need to take in order to get Nginx and Node.js to play nicely.

I went to the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and updated this block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

to this block:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;  # change to your port if needed
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

And then updated my Node app to serve files through Express with `app.use(express.static('/var/www/html'));`.

Here are a couple of links that helped lead me to the right answer:

[Node.js + Nginx - What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-node-js-server-with-nginx

And an extra link I found which tells you more about the Nginx directives used:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html