# nginx reverse proxy nodejs subdomain

Tags: node.js, nginx, plesk

I am having a problem.

I have a node application running on `:3000` on a subdomain inside of Plesk.

I have the subdomain `https://xxx.flamingocams.co.uk` ;
when I navigate to the subdomain it displays the default plesk page and this is the problem;

I have tried to change the port of the node application to 80 and 443 however this conflicts with plesk.
I have no issues when accessing the node application on `https://xxx.flamingocams.co.uk:3000`.

Now the only other thing I've seen other people attempt is a reverse proxy;

I found this [example](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/nginx-subdomain-vhost-solved.334129/);

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name xxx.flamingocams.co.uk;
        access_log "/var/log/nginx/xxxflam.log";
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

I am running    `Plesk Obsidian v18.0.34_build1800210325.10 os_Ubuntu 16.04` so my question is, Where would I place this config to get the subdomain to point only to the nodejs application?

And is this config correct for what I'm trying to achieve?

I have little to no knowledge on nginx configuration my apologies

I have checked out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009324/node-js-nginx-what-now?rq=1)  and the answer says I need to add a config /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain.com however I do not have the directory `sites-available`

**response to comments // xxx.flamingocams.co.uk.conf**

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name xxx.flamingocams.co.uk;
        access_log "/var/log/nginx/xxxflam.log";
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:443;
        server_name xxx.flamingocams.co.uk;
        ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfZc0CwJ;
        ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfZc0CwJ;
        server_name xxx.flamingocams.co.uk;
        access_log "/var/log/nginx/xxxflam.log";
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config, the server is running only on port 80

```
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
```

With this config, the page : http://xxx.flamingocams.co.uk will display your application (the request come to the NginX proxy then is forwarded to NodeJS application on port 3000). Because there aren't any `server` block listen on port 443, the default Plesk screen is displayed.

In order to have your app running on https, you need to listen on port 443 on NginX, you also need to configure the SSL certificate

The config would be :

```
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:443;
        server_name xxx.flamingocams.co.uk;
        ssl_certificate     path_to_your_ssl_certificate;
        ssl_certificate_key path_to_your_ssl_key;

        # The rest of your config is ok :)

}
```

Comment: I have tried overtwriting the conf file found in `/etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/xxx.flamingocams.co.uk` but it just overwrites upon reboot?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it just overwrites upon reboot' ? The content of the file is overwrite when you reboot ?

Comment: yeah when i restart or use the comand nginx -s reload it recreated the conf file

Comment: I would say it is something special in the server, I don't have any knowledge about plesk though.. :) You may need to looking for plesk documentation about how to overwrite the configuration.

Comment: It looks good for me, just 1 thing: the certificate and the key point to the same file, is it normal?